# Connecting a new audio device makes previous one show as "unplugged" (Kubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I have two headphone jacks on my PC, one in the front, and another in the back. When my headset is plugged into the back port, everything works fine; "Line Out (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)" shows up as a playback device, and I encounter no problems. However, when I plug in my speakers to the front port, all sound switches to them (which show up as "Headphones (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" in the playback device list) and Line Out shows up as unplugged in the Audio Volume menu in system settings. The headset is then unusable, if I want sound to play on it, I have to unplug the speakers. When I do that, Line Out stops showing as unplugged and works correctly again.

What I want to do is use Line Out as the default playback device even when the front headphone jack is connected, and manually switch to the latter when I need to. I'm pretty sure this should be simple enough given that Line Out actually stays usable when I plug in my speakers.

I'm no expert on how things like this work in Ubuntu, so please tell me if more information is needed, and how exactly to get there. Thanks in advance.